# Perl Element Frequency within Arrays

Tags: arrays, perl, element, frequency

I have a txt input file of a short story. Once I've read the txt file into my program, how would I find the frequency of every single term? For example, how many times the word "the" appears, and how many times the word "I" appears, except for every single unique term within the array.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You are expected to have a specific programming problem and, ideally, be able to show some code that demonstrates it. *“I can't write Perl”* isn't really that sort of problem.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, you would [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) the input on typical delimiters (spaces, punctuation, etc.) and loop through the resulting array of words, updating a [hash table](http://www.tizag.com/perlT/perlhashes.php) of key-value pairs in which a key is a word and the value is a number representing the frequency, or number of times that word appears. Consider edge cases, like how you might [handle](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/lc.html) keys when dealing with words that start with an uppercase letter, or perhaps more complicated issues like hyphenated words in unjustified text. Hopefully this answer will help you search for and think about the Perl terminology and general concepts that you'll want to learn.